# Conditionals in \foreach loops

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, foreach, loops

I drew a ruler using the MWE below then I realized that It draws each medium (5 mm step) vertical line over the small ones (1 mm step) and each large (numbered) vertical bar over both medium and small ones. So, my question is: how to use conditionals to prevent overlapping?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[{x=(1mm,0)},{y=(0,1mm)}]
        \tiny
        \draw
            (0,0)
            rectangle(150,-15)
        ;

        \foreach \x in {5, 6, ..., 145}{
            \draw (\x, 0)--(\x, -2);
        }
        \foreach \y in {5, 10, ..., 145}{
            \draw (\y, 0)--(\y, -4);
        }
        \foreach \z in {5, 15, ..., 145}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{(\z - 5)/10}
            \draw (\z, 0)--(\z, -6) node[below]{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=0]{\d}};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're right, it draws a few ticks too often but this should only be a render issue, another PDF viewer and your printer will output this differently. (But it's a good idea to surpress these anyway.)

Comment: I just noticed that the 5s and 10s can be totally distinctive loops: with my setup one for `0, 10, ..., 140` and the other for `5, 15, ..., 135`. The smallest tick might be solved by two nested loops: `\foreach \x in {0, ..., 13} \foreach \xx in {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}` and then use `10*\x + \xx` as the *x* value.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is an easier approach:

We use one loop to go through all ticks and check for each one whether it is divisible by 10 and 5 and choose the appropriate length.

The function `mod(<x>, <n>)` returns the remainder of `<x>/<n>` but `0` will be interpreted by `ifthenelse` as false where as all other results will be interpreted as true.

Of course, you can put the whole function for `\ticklength` directly into the path:

```
\draw (\x, 0) -- +(down:{ifthenelse(mod(\x, 10), ifthenelse(mod(\x, 5), 2, 4), 6)};
```

but if you need it more than once, the `evaluate` key is a good tool for it.

For the numbers we could use the same loop with another conditional test in various ways but it seems easier to just emply a second loop that iterates directly over the integers. (We could actually write `\x0` instead of `10*\x` but the latter is syntactical more correct, I guess.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
\tiny
\draw (-5 ,0) rectangle (145, -15);

\foreach[
  evaluate={
    \ticklength=
      ifthenelse(mod(\x, 10),
        ifthenelse(mod(\x, 5), 2, 4), 6);}] \x in {0, ..., 140}
  \draw (\x, 0) -- +(down:\ticklength);
\foreach \x in {0, ..., 14}
  \node[below] at (10*\x, -6) {$\x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(too long for a comment)*

Your question is clear, but in my opinion, such the overlappings do not matter. It's not difficult to avoid such the overlappings, but the price we have to pay is the complexity and readibility of codes.

Your ruler figure reminds me one of the first `tikzpicture`s I have drawn. Hope the code is helpful for someone.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,x=1mm,y=1mm]
% a ruler
\fill[gray!20] (0,-2) rectangle (100,0);
\foreach \i in {0,...,100} 
    \draw (\i,0)--+(0,-2);
\foreach \i in {0,...,20} 
    \draw (5*\i,0)--+(0,-4);
\foreach \i in {0,...,10}
    \draw (10*\i,0)--++(0,-6) node[below]{\i};
\draw (0,-12) node[align=left]{cm};
\draw[thick,rounded corners] (-5,-20) rectangle (105,0);

% a pink pencil
\begin{scope}[yshift=4pt]
\fill[red!60] (0,0) rectangle (85,1.5);
\fill[red!40] (0,1.5) rectangle (85,3.5);
\fill[red!20] (0,3.5) rectangle (85,5);
\fill[black!50] (95,2.5) circle(1pt);
\fill[draw=black,left color=white,right color=black!20] (85,0)--(95,2.5)--(85,5);
\draw[black!50,opacity=.5] (0,0) rectangle (85,5);              
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```